# How to do AJAX POST call in express.js file in handlebar?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am trying to send/update data to mongoDB database via AAJAX call but the command is not reaching theere. I have tried debugging using alert in between the code but the command is not reaching there. Means AJAX call doesn't get executed.

Below is my AJAX POST request code:

```
var text = "Done";

var data = {
  selectedValue: text
}

$ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/update-sources',
  dataType: 'text/json',
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          alert("Working!!")
      }
});
```

And Below is the /update-sources route code:

```
router.post('/update-sources', function(req, res, next) {
console.log("/Update-Sources")
  User.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.user.email}, {$set:{status:data.selectedValue}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
      }
  else
   {
     res.render('taskswriter');
     console.log(doc);
     return "Great Working!";
    }
  });

    });
```

What mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you shared browser's console output, but trying to execute attached client-side snippet, I got the following error:

```
VM219:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajax is not defined
    at <anonymous>:7:1
```

You've got a typo there - it should be `$.ajax` as you are accessing a function from within *jQuery namespace* (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)